# Transparent border in WPF programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

It's trivial to generate a border (to use for Trackball events) transparent over the viewport in the XAML file:

```
<Border Name="myElement" Background="Transparent" />
```

But how do I do it in the .cs?

```
Border border = new Border();
**border.Background = (VisualBrush)Colors.Transparent;**
grid.Children.Add(viewport);
grid.Children.Add(border);
```

This does not work of course.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is because you can't just cast a Color to be a Brush. use the [Transparent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brushes.transparent.aspx) brush instead

```
border.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a `SolidColorBrush`:

```
border.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
```

The `VisualBrush` has a different purpose. See an overview of the main types of WPF brushes here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970904.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can also create a SolidColorBrush with transparent color:
This will create a fully transparent color

```
border.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

but you can also make semitransparent color by changing alpha (this will look like 50% transparent red:

```
border.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, 255, 0, 0));
```