# button Background transparent not set in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

WPF: i have a button and the image was set in code behind c#

```
 btn.Content = new Image
                    {
                        Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(MasterVariables.applicationPath + "Normal.png")),
                        Stretch = Stretch.Fill,
                    };
```

now problem is while over into the button the background color set as blue but i change the image in mouse_enter event

```
 btn.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
            btn.Style = (Style)FindResource(ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey);
            btn.Background = Brushes.White; btn.BorderBrush = Brushes.Transparent;
           btn.Content = new Image
                    {
                        Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(MasterVariables.applicationPath + "Hover.png")),
                        Stretch = Stretch.Fill,
                    };
```

the image was change but while over into mouse the backgrounded is highlighted in blue color

Comment: Handle the proper events then change the properties, but the best way is from xaml

Answer (score 0):

Update your style to trigger background on MouseOver:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property='IsMouseOver' Value='True'>
        <Setter Property='Background' Value='White' />
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: ismouseover not worked.is any other idea.? i need to change in c# not in xmal code

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" TargetName="panel" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

and more information refer this sites

[How do you change Background for a Button MouseOver in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259280/how-do-you-change-background-for-a-button-mouseover-in-wpf)

[Transparent button background in WPF using style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163003/transparent-button-background-in-wpf-using-style)

Comment: i tried all the xaml code but it not worked. still it shows blue color. (i need the changes in c#)

Comment: Try This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585542/transparent-border-in-wpf-programmaticaly